# Bluetooth audio amplification

Tags: single-supply-op-amp

I made a circuit that consists of an operational amplifier and some capacitors and transistors so I can amplify the coming signal from any voice. Now I want to make this signal come from a Bluetooth module. How should make this connection?
simply I want the signal that comes from my phone to be reserved by any Bluetooth module like (HC-06) and then this signal enters the op-amp circuit to be amplified. But the problem is that I don't know how to connect the Bluetooth module to the circuit.

Comment: What Bluetooth module?  Do you want to transmit the audio over Bluetooth to another receiver?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The interface to the Bluetooth module will normally be documented in its datasheet.

It looks like the hc-06 module you've chosen simply doesn't have an audio interface, so unless there's something there that's not obvious in the documentation, it's probably just not suitable for the task at hand.

Just doing a quick search, one of the first datasheets that came up with a documented audio interface was:

https://www.tinyosshop.com/datasheet/TS8670_datasheet.pdf

I've never used this one, so I'm not recommending it, just using it as an example. It documents:

> - Stereo or dual mono analogue audio output through
>   SPK_LP, SPK_LN, SPK_RP, SPK_RN.
> - Stereo and mono analogue input through MIC_LN, MIC_LP, MIC_RN, MIC_RP. The module is designed for different [sic] output,if a single-ended audio output is required,use an external differential to single-ended converter.

Depending on what your op-amp circuit looks like, you may or may not want/need to redesign it a bit. This produces a balanced output, but chances are pretty good that your circuit currently has a single-ended input (even though the op-amp itself will normally have a balanced input). You may need/want to redesign a bit to feed its balanced output more directly to the +/- inputs of your op-amp, rather than (as I'd guess you have now) using single-ended transmission when both its output and your op-amp's input are both balanced.

Of course, that's just the introductory material, pointing toward what interfaces this particular chip provides. To do much with it, you want/need to look through the rest of the datasheet. Also, as it stands right now, that's just documentation for a chip. From the sound of things, you probably want a complete, pre-built module.

You can certainly find those with audio interfaces as well, but again, it's largely a matter of finding a suitable device (one with audio interfaces) and reading the datasheet to find what connections to make. Here's one example (but again, only an example):

https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/268/BM20_23_Bluetooth_Stereo_Audio_Module_DS70005406C-2887185.pdf